# Updating whole table without ID iteration

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Notice: It's all done in test enviroment

**Problem**
I have 3 tables
- invoices
- products
- connection between them

Now I need to update EVERY invoice, with some values from products.

**Question**
How can I do that without iterating trough ID

**What I have tried so far**
1.SELECT data I need

```
SELECT INV.id, INV.to_update, SUM(PRO.update_from)
FROM invoices INV
LEFT JOIN connecting CNN ON CNN.id_inv=INV.id
LEFT JOIN products PRO ON PRO.id = CNN.id_prod
GROUP by INV.id;
```

It will display me right values.
[image]

2.Update iterating trough ID (PHP/C# or other language)

```
UPDATE invoices INV SET INV.to_update=
  (SELECT SUM(PRO.update_from) 
  FROM connecting CNN 
  LEFT JOIN products PRO ON PRO.id=CNN.id_prod 
  WHERE CNN.id_inv="+id+") 
WHERE INV.id="+id+"
```

**Problem**
I can not use any "loop" form PHP, or c# or any other language. I need to do that just in SQL. So is there a way to do that in SQL without SELECTING all ID's of invoices, and iterating trough them?

**Explanation and Tables**
I am forced to work on this database. Every product have `update_from` column, with a value. I need to SUM all values from all products from this invoice, and put this SUM into one of the column of Invoices (in case `update_from` changed for products in the future, it needs to stay same for invoice.

Columns that matters:
Invoices: `ID, to_update` *//need to put SUM into that column*
Connecting: `ID, id_prod, id_inv` *//id of a product, and id of invoice*
Products: `ID, update_from` *//need to SUM that*

Of course, 1 invoice might have many products, hence the "SUM" of `update_from`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do the update you want completely with SQL code:

```
UPDATE invoices 
    JOIN connecting 
        ON invoices.id = connecting.id_inv
    JOIN products 
        ON products.id= connecting.id_prod
    SET invoices.to_update= SUM(products.update_from)
```

Note: I'm not sure but you may need to use left joins with ifnull, instead of join, depends on your data, you can check it

Comment: Oh, I can use JOINs with UPDATE also? Interesting.. Will try this and read a little about it and then I will get back to you!

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE  invoices
SET     to_update = (
        select   sum(p.update_from)
        FROM    invoices i2 join connecting c on c.id_inv = i2.id
                join products p on p.id = c.id_prod
        where   i2.id = invoices.id)
```

Comment: This will update ALL rows of `invoices` table with the same value

Comment: I don't think it will.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.